# Not enough arguments for format string in INSERTION of csv file

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

i want to insert into users the csv file and especially the bellow query checking if an entry is already in , so don't reinsert it. When i am running this i am getting the error " Not enough arguments for format string" i know in the query i am giving "13 %s" and in the row is 11 , so how can i balance them?

```
sql1="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,first_name varchar(255),last_name varchar(255),company_name varchar(255),address varchar(255),city varchar(255),country varchar(255),postal varchar(255),phone1 varchar(255),phone2 varchar(255),email varchar(255),web varchar(255),PRIMARY KEY(id))"
cursorobject.execute(sql1)
csvfile=open('Entries.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    cursorobject.execute("INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,company_name,address,city,country,postal,phone1,phone2,email,web)SELECT %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name=%s AND last_name=%s))",row)
```

Comment: Add two more...

Comment: Not directly related, but that `insert...select` looks like it is not going to work out the way you think; depending on parameters for first_name and last_name, it'll either do nothing, or double the number of rows in the table. Probably should be using `FROM DUAL` instead.

Comment: Aaaanyways, you should be using a UNIQUE index instead of doing this broken-ass duplicate checking regardless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you be more specific with code?